# How to apply folder hierarchy with npm publish --registry?

Tags: gitlab-ci, nexus, package.json, npm-publish, npm-version

I am not sure where to change in command line for npm publish or package.json file for npm. I am trying to structure the Nexus repository using the version. I have written a gitlab ci/cd pipeline. The result that I want in Nexus dashboard is

```
- ProjectName
  - v1.0.0
    - artifacts.zip
  - v2.0.0
    - artifacts.zip
```

[image]

I have the following pipeline written:

```
npm publish --registry $Nexus_REPO_URL
```